# Creating references that are bracketed numbers, not citation

Tags: microsoft-word, reference-book

I am writing up a report in Microsoft Word and I need to include references. However, the style I am writing in requires that the references be written like:

> ...which is why they decided to attack [5]. ....

**and not**

> ...which is why they decided to attack (The Fifteen Decisive Battles of the World, 1851)

However, Microsoft Word 2010 seems to offer no way to support this. I've searched everywhere I could and all tutorials show how to create either footnotes, or the second scenario presented above.

Please let me know whether it's possible for me to do what I am trying to.

Comment: Where does [5] point to? A sources cited page, rather than footnotes?

Comment: @Raystafarian yes exactly.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have figured out the answer.

The style of Reference page I would like to use is called `IEEE`.  In the `Citations and Bibliography` section of the `References` tab, there is a menu for `Style`. If you select that, `IEEE` is one of the options.

[image: IEEE Citation Style]

So overall the steps are:

1. Click `Insert Citation` > `Add a New Source`
2. Enter the source into the wizard page.
3. Click OK. Now your citation is in the list when you click "Insert Citation". Whenver you reach somewhere in the document where you want to refer to that reference, click `Insert Citation` and select it.
4. When you are ready,  generate a Bibliography by clicking `Bibliography` > `Insert Bibliography`.

**NOTE**: If you don't see the `IEEE` format as an option, you need to install it, as @Kesavan points out below. If the link he provided didn't work, go HERE, download `styles.zip`, unzip it, then copy all the `.xsl` files (each representing a different style) into the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Bibliography\Style` or equivalent on your machine.

Comment: If the links are not working use this. http://mikemurko.com/general/ieee-referencing-for-word-2007-2010/

Comment: Links doesn't work. Use this instead https://heather.sh/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/IEEE_Reference.zip

Answer (score 5):

Solution is Here
You have to install the IEEE Reference Number Style
https://www.letuslook.org/tips-tricks/install-additional-word-reference-styles-mac-windows/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Answer (score 2):

I am on a Mac Word 2011 so the above answers were helpful conceptually. These were the steps that I needed to follow to get this working:

1. I got the IEEE .XSL style from Bibword 
   http://bibword.codeplex.com/ (look for the Download button once there)
2. Clicking the download button downloaded a styles.zip file
3. Extract the .zip file, go inside and copy all of the .XSL files (or just the ones that you want)
4. Go over to Finder > Microsoft Office > Word. Then [Show Package Contents]
5. Content > Resources > Styles. And paste the .XSL files there
6. Restart Word

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word has `ISO 690 - Numerical Reference` built-in as an option for citation style.

1. In the ribbon, go to `References`
2. locate the ribbon section titled `Citations & Bibliography`
3. in the `Style` drop-down menu, chose `ISO 690 - Numerical Reference`

The citation will simply show as (X), where X is an integer referencing the numbered source in the `Bibliography` object once you have inserted one somewhere in your document.

No need for any add-on or anything.
This is on Microsoft Word 365, version 2002, build 12527.21104 .

As per Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_690) :

> ISO 690 is an ISO standard governing bibliographic references in different kinds of documents, including electronic documents. This international standard specifies the bibliographic elements that need to be included in references to published documents, and the order in which these elements should be stated.

Answer (score 0):

anyone looking for this in libreoffice

> Look in Insert -> Indexes and Tables -> Index and Table... then under
>   type select Bibliography. You can then customise the options quite a
>   lot. You can specify which fields are used for the entries in the
>   Bibliography and in what order for the different types of bibliography
>   entries that are pre-defined.
>
> When you want to add a reference in a document use Insert -> Indexes
>   and Tables -> Bibliography Entry.

source: 2012 https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/455/is-there-a-tool-to-manage-bibliography/?answer=4433#post-id-4433